# set http headers in google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, http-headers

I was making a web app using google apps script, and I have been getting errors like this:

```
Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://script.google.com/.../exec?url=style.css' from origin 'https://...-script.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Access to script at 'https://script.google.com/.../exec?url=script.js' from origin 'https://...-script.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

how would I add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

```
function doGet(e){
  var t,r;
//...
  if(t=='text/html'||t=='text/x-server-parsed-html'){return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(r);}
  r=ContentService.createTextOutput(r);
  r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  if(/[^\/]+?\/([^.]+?\.)?([^+]+?\+)?xml/.test(t)){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);}
  if(t=='application/atom+xml'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.ATOM);}
  if(t=='text/csv'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.CSV);}
  if(t=='text/calendar'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.ICAL);}
  if(t=='application/javascript'||t=='text/javascript'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);}
  if(t=='application/json'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);}
  if(t=='application/rss+xml'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);}
  if(t=='text/vcard'){r.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.VCARD);}
  if(e.parameter.name){r.downloadAsFile(e.parameter.name)}
  return r;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Use `simple` requests that doesn't need to be preflighted.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the CORS headers in a Google Apps Script webapp. This is done by Google to ensure the security of their users.

I see, however, that you are attempting to fetch files such as `style.css` or `script.js`. If this is the case - and you are using the "classic" HTML tags for including them (such as `<link rel="stylesheet" ...` and `<script src=...` I suggest you do the following instead:

1. Replace the `style.css` file for a `style.html` HTML file, the contents of which should be as follows:

   ```html
   <style>
   ...
   </style>
   ```

   Where the `...` should be your CSS code.
2. Replace the `script.js` file for a `script.html` HTML file, the contents of which should be:

   ```html
   <script>
   ...
   </script>
   ```

   Where `...` should be your script code.
3. Include the newly create files above in your main HTML by using scriptlets (see the example below). Find the location of your HTML file in which you want to inject the code, and use the following tags, as appropriate, to do so:

   ```
   <?!= include('style'); ?>
   ```

   ```
   <?!= include('script'); ?>
   ```

#### Example

*Code.gs*

```js
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

*Page.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Stylesheet.html*

```html
<style>
p {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

*JavaScript.html*

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

#### References

- [Google Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript)